# Lucene Query syntax equivalent to LIKE operator in SQL

Tags: java, lucene

What is the equivalent syntax of LIKE operation (used in SQL) for Lucene search?

I have a specific query to filter: "I have a list of java objects where the string of names is separated by comma (,) how to filter the list using specific name"?

Comment: A wildcard? https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard%20Searches Seems like the Lucene docs and/or examples would have been quicker since this is a pretty common thing?

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton...Can these wildcards (? *) be used for exact match of a word. Exact match in the scene, lets say I have names1 = "John, Mary".  And names2 = "Steve, Johnson". In my result, I want the names having John. i.e. names1 and not names2. Can I write condition something like `lastName : 'Smit' AND name : 'John?'`

Answer (score -1):

I know this was a basic question. But I'm not familiar with lucene that much. If someone novice facing same issue, you can use regex in string query to achieve this. I have also used the same.